# How to get access to local machine certificate in a windows service running in docker container?

Tags: azure, docker, windows-services

I'm having trouble finding a certificate by thumbprint in a windows service that's running in a docker container. I'm very new to Docker and I appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction.

Verified the thumbprint being searched is correct.

I've tried to manually install the cert to the container:

```
    Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\cert.pfx  -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root -Exportable -Password $Secure_String_Pwd
```

Verified it is installed in the right location.

I've tried to give "Everyone" FullControl access to the private key.

This is the code in the windows service that tries to find the cert. I'm getting 0 in results from certStore.Certificates.Find() function. This is returning one result when run in a VM with the same certificate installed.

```
    X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var certs = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, true);
    if (certs.Count == 0)
        throw new CryptographicException("Could not find requested certificate.");
```

DockerFile:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.7.1-windowsservercore-ltsc2016

    COPY ["Services", "C:/Services"]
    COPY ["Cert.pfx", "C:/"]
    COPY ["AddUserToCert.ps1", "C:/"]

    RUN sc create NLPEngineService binpath= "c:/Services/Service.exe c:/Services/Service.exe.config" start= auto
```

Docker Commands:

```
    docker build -t testservice-docker .\
    docker run -it testservice-docker cmd
```

Comment: What error do you get? please provide the error message.

Comment: Hi Charles, I'm not getting an error. I'm getting 0 results from certStore.Certificates.Find() function. I suspect the docker container doesn't have access to the certificates installed in the server but I'm not sure.